# MySQL order by IF and sorting dates

Tags: mysql, sorting

In sorting the ORDER BY of dates in MySQL, I'm trying to sort ASC for dates after today, and DESC for dates before today in one go.

I'm doing something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IF(created >= NOW(), created, 1) ASC, created DESC
```

This gives me a somewhat desired result:

```
ID  CREATED
8   May, 10 2014 11:15:00+0000
7   May, 03 2014 20:47:00+0000
5   May, 02 2014 14:00:00+0000
4   April, 30 2014 17:41:00+0000
3   April, 30 2014 17:00:00+0000
1   April, 21 2014 03:30:00+0000
6   March, 23 2014 12:00:00+0000
9   May, 20 2014 20:45:00+0000
10  July, 02 2014 20:30:00+0000
2   June, 30 2015 11:16:00+0000
```

Before today is DESC, after today is ASC. However, I want to see the block of ID's 9,10,2 at the top of the results.

Any thoughts on how to do this is appreciated.

Test Link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4667b/2/0

Comment: is there any specific logic behind  9,10,2 on the top since they are after today.

Comment: Just for order. This is for events. I want to show what's coming up sooner rather than later but also show what's past in order from most recently passed to oldest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional condition to the `order by`, which is a binary indicator of whether the date is in the past or future:

```
SELECT *
FROM test 
ORDER BY (created >= NOW()) desc,
         IF(created >= NOW(), created, NULL) ASC,
         created DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about splitting it up into 2 sql queries and then unioning the results?

```
(SELECT * FROM test WHERE created >= NOW() ORDER BY created ASC)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM test WHERE created < NOW() ORDER BY created DESC)
```

Comment: The results from a `union` are not doing to be in the order in the subqueries.  The results of a `union all` might seem to be, but there is no guarantee.